# prevent scroll position change in one html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

without using any framework I'm doing this kind of transition : http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://daysof.me/57/promo/debug.html

but I've problem dealing with the position. In my above demo, try to scroll down and click on the second item, you will see the flick. This is not css issue, this is position issue.

I tried my research, jquery mobile have their own build in thing call silentscroll, but how I address my problem because I'm not using any of those framework?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to fix the position of the `Back` button in the `Test 3` part of your link, is that right ?

For that, you'll have to apply

```
 { position : fixed; }
```

on the `Back` element.
You might also want to set a height to the paragraph, along with

```
 { overflow : scroll;}
```

Comment: No.. Why I said jquery mobile if I merely want to fix the back's css?